# SSIS Variable Issue --- Get MAX date from a SQL table through SSIS?? (Have it set up and working, but it stores the run date)

Tags: sql, sql-server, automation, ssis, etl

Trying to do something seemingly simple, however, it is not working as expected. It does not error.

I have a table with many rows and dates over the past year. The newest should be like '2022-07-23' after casting, but the query returns today '2022-08-08 3:07 PM'

I simply have an Execute SQL Task with this line (which gives correct result if run in SSMS):

```
SELECT MAX(ITEM_DATE) AS MaxDateVal
FROM MyDatabase.MySchema.MyTable
```

Again, if run in SSMS, it gives the exact result desired.

When run in SSIS, it gives the current/run date down to the minute. My setup is as follows. Apologies if I missed any relevant info, but I think this covers it (note the scope variables in the second picture at the bottom).

Please let me know if you know how to fix this. I imagine it's something super easy that I am just not seeing.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The value `2022-08-08 3:07 PM` must come from somewhere, is there such a row? Are you sure you are connecting to the right database and schema?

Comment: Agreed try connecting to different data source or else try that query using an expression

Comment: @Charlieface I checked the table/connection. There is no column or cell value for that matter that is '2022-08-08', so I have no idea where it is coming from, other than the run time. If the variable is already populated, the date does not change to the new runtime but if I reset the variable so that it shows a blank value in the Variables section of SSIS, it does repopulate with the new runtime. 

Interestingly, if I change the sql syntax to get Max(project), which is a text field, it does not return everything. Either of these queries (new and old) work perfectly fine if executed in SSMS.

Comment: @AkshayPhadke I verified the Data Source is correct and the connection test was successful. No luck there. What do you mean by doing it as an expression? I've tried tinkering with that a bit, but can't get an expression that works (always get a cast error or truncation error no matter what). I will keep trying but do you know what I should input for the "expression" to cast the variable I have created?